# Cannot start Tomcat server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I am new at Linux and Tomcat and trying to install Tomcat properly. What I did is extract apache-tomcat-7.029 and openjdk.

I set the profile file and the paths like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
export CATALINA_HOME=/root/tomcat
```

the result of

```
java -version
```

is this:

```
java version "1.6.0_34"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_34-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.9-b04, mixed mode)
```

and when I say

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

it returns me:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

but when I try to use tomcat with either

```
http://MY_IP_address:8080/
```

I get this error:

```
 http://MY_IP_address:8080:No such file or directory
```

Comment: are you entering the url in your terminal?

Comment: yes I do enter on terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Open your browser and 
in the `url` type

`http://your_IP_address:8080/` for example

`http://192.168.0.100:8080` or `http://locahost:8080`

Comment: Timeout error. I think I have no permission to reach it since its in cloud. Can I test if tomcat works from terminal?

Comment: @gbesler I am not sure but for running any web apps you need to keep it in tomcat/webapps folder.If you dont have permission then how can you keep the app

Comment: @gbesler in windows we check if the port is open or not by running telnet.I am not sure in linux whether this command exists or not.

Comment: I understand what you said but I cant reach the server by a browser. ssh is the only way to do it. just trying to understand if tomcat is up or down.

Comment: Yes it is helpful but not the solution.

Answer (score 2):

open your browser and type

```
http://locahost:8080
```

and once check Apache tomcat service is started or not

Steps:
  start-control panel-administrative tools-services
  and check apache tomcat. 
If service is not started then right click and start the server before running apache tomcat

I have tried this and it's working fine

Comment: the server is on cloud. I cant reach it except ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Enter `http://localhost:8080` in your browser.
If you want to access it from another computer with your IP address, you may try to find the firewall settings of your OS and make sure the port 8080(in your case) is open.